# How to pass data from partial page to main laravel master pages?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have made my navigation file a partial file because it is commonly needed in every pages.
In navigation bar there are lists of categories displayed. When i click one of the categories, i want to it to display it in another pages. For that i need to send id form that navigation bar categories. 
I tried to send id from the navigation bar then it shows error like
 **Missing required parameters for [Route: details] [URI: HamroBazar/details/{id}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\hamrobazarfinal\resources\views\Frontend\partial\loggedinnavigation.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\hamrobazarfinal\resources\views\Frontend\partial\loggedinnavigation.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\hamrobazarfinal\resources\views\Frontend\partial\loggedinnavigation.blade.php)**

Here are some code

```
Navigation bar code (This is the partial file)
<div class="w3layouts-breadcrumbs">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <span class="agile-breadcrumbs">
      <span class="categories1" >All Categories<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></span>   
      @foreach($categoriespostcount as $cn)
      <a href="{{route('details',['id'=>$cn->id])}}">{{$cn->categoryname}}<span>({{$cn->postads->count()}})</span></a> 
      @endforeach
    </div>
  </div>
```

Web.php

```
Route::get('details/{id}','Detail\DetailController@details')->name('details');
```

Controller

```
 public function details($id)
    {
        dd($id);
        return view('Frontend.pages.detail.detail');
    }
```

Comment: Can you dd($categoriespostcount) to ensure it has the id property intact? Possibly you are sending a request to details/undefined ?

Comment: @Anders It shows LengthAwarePaginator but  the page contents are overflown.

Comment: Are you using an API to get the data? Not 100% sure, but I think you want to get the "data" key from the paginator object.

Comment: @Anders Nope nothing like that

Comment: @Anders  view()->share('categoriespostcount',Category::with('postads')->where('parent_id','=',0)->paginate(11)); i wrote this on appserviceprovider

Comment: Ok, then use items() or similar as described here: https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html

Comment: @Anders I got the Solution. Thank you for your time and response.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know i have to put '?' in the route.

```
Route::get('details/{id?}','Detail\DetailController@details')->name('details');
```